# App crashing when I install firebase package for my React Native App(IOS/Android)?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

React Native Expo: The app isn't loading after I add the firebase dependency.

I tried installing different versions of firebase but it still didn't work.

Comment: Did you followed this doc https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/ properly

Comment: What version of firebase are you installing ?